# SPWebConfigModification is throwing an error

Tags: 2007, administration, web-config, powershell

I am trying to update the web.config file through Powershell using the SharePoint class "SPWebConfigModification" however facing the issue mentioned below, please help me to fix this.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 
$url = New-Object System.Uri("http://serverName:port/")
$webApp = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($url) 
$mod = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification" 
$mod.Path = "configuration/system.web/customErrors"
$mod.Name = "mode"
$mod.Sequence = 0
$mod.Owner = "powershell" 
$mod.Type = "EnsureAttribute"
$mod.Value = "Off"
$webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add($mod)
$webApp.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications() 
$webApp.Update()
```

**Error:**

`Exception calling "ApplyWebConfigModifications" with "0" argument(s): "'' is an invalid expression."
At line:1 char:47
+ $webApp.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a new Web Application?

Often when dealing with `SPWebConfigModification` the `ApplyWebConfigModifications()` call will fail because of an earlier broken `SPWebConfigModification` that is sitting in the collection.

Try the following to see if there's anything unexpected in there

```
$webApp.WebConfigModifications | Format-Table Name,Owner
```

if the only things in there are yours, try  `$webApp.WebConfigModifications.Clear()` first, otherwise you can clear it out by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](http://www.iwkid.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=10) where the author is doing the same thing more or less, however he calls Update() BEFORE calling ApplyWebConfigModifications(). You might want to try that.

Comment: I tried that too but still the result is same....!

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your script I run a test and seems to be working fine (on a web app with port number and also on another without)

Are you running this from the server where front end `http://serverName:port/` runs ?

Comment: The script also runs for me using http://localhost as the url on SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to get a more detailed stacktrace of the exception.

[detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751/can-i-get-detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell/798136#798136)

Answer (score 0):

.Type is looking for an Enum, not the string "EnsureAttribute"
The easiest way I've found to handle this is use Visual Studio to determine the value of the enum you're looking for.  EnsureAttribute is 1, so change 
$mod.Type = "EnsureAttribute" to be 
$mod.Type = 1
and you should be good to go.

Comment: Powershell can coerce strings to enums.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
$webApp.WebConfigModifications.Clear()